# React Recorded video not playing in video tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, material-ui, webcam

I'm creating a React application for conducting webcam interviews with candidates. Candidates can also "Start Again" or "Complete" their interviews.

To display the recorded data, I'm attempting to show it as an HTML video. However, I'm facing an issue where the video doesn't appear after recording. The video data is currently in blob format.

Additionally, I've included a download button; when users download the video, it works correctly and saves locally.

I've tried a few solutions to resolve the display issue. I've attempted to directly embed the video using .mp4 or .webm extensions in the src attribute. I've also experimented with third-party React video player npm packages. Unfortunately, none of these approaches have been successful so far.

```
import Webcam from 'react-webcam';
const Index = (props) => {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);
  const [totalTime, setTotalTime] = useState(0);
  const [video, setVideo] = useState(null);
  const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);

  const [isVideoComplete, setIsVideoComplete] = useState(false);
  const [webcamLoading, setWebcamLoading] = useState(true);

  const webcamRef = useRef(null);
  const mediaRecorderRef = useRef(null);
  const timeIntervalRef = useRef(null);
  const [recordedChunks, setRecordedChunks] = useState([]);

  const maxRecordingTime = 180;

  const videoConstraints = {
    aspectRatio: 0.6666666667,
    width: 1280,
    height: 720,
    facingMode: 'user',
  };

  const audioConstraints = {
    suppressLocalAudioPlayback: true,
    noiseSuppression: true,
    echoCancellation: true,
  };


  const stopTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(timeIntervalRef.current);
  };

  const formatTime = (seconds) => {
    const minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    const remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    return `${minutes}:${remainingSeconds < 10 ? '0' : ''}${remainingSeconds}`;
  };

  const handleDataAvailable = React.useCallback(
    ({ data }) => {
      if (data.size > 0) {
        setRecordedChunks((prev) => prev.concat(data));
      }
    },
    [setRecordedChunks]
  );
  // Stop Recording
  const handleStopRecording = useCallback(() => {
    setIsVideoComplete(true);
    setShowStats(true);
    stopTimer();
    console.log(isRecording, mediaRecorderRef.current);
    if (isRecording && mediaRecorderRef.current) {
      setIsRecording(false);
      const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: 'video/webm' });
      // Blob { size: 0, type: 'video/webm' }
      console.log(blob);
      setVideo(blob);

      mediaRecorderRef.current.stop();
    }
  }, [isRecording, recordedChunks]);

  const startTimer = useCallback(() => {
    setTimer(0);
    timeIntervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTimer((prevTimer) => {
        if (prevTimer >= maxRecordingTime) {
          handleStopRecording();
          return prevTimer;
        }
        return prevTimer + 1;
      });
    }, 1000);
  }, [handleStopRecording]);
  
  // Start Recording
  const handleStartRecording = useCallback(() => {
    setShowStats(false);
    setIsVideoComplete(false);
    if (!isRecording) {
      setIsRecording(true);
      startTimer();
      if (webcamRef.current && webcamRef.current.video.srcObject) {
        const stream = webcamRef.current.video.srcObject;
        mediaRecorderRef.current = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
          mimeType: 'video/webm',
        });
        mediaRecorderRef.current.addEventListener('dataavailable', handleDataAvailable);
        mediaRecorderRef.current.start();
      }
    }
  }, [handleDataAvailable, isRecording, startTimer]);

  const handleCompleteRecording = () => {
    setShowStats(true);
    if (video) {
      sendVideo(video);
    }
  };
   
   // Download Video
   const handleDownload = React.useCallback(() => {
     if (recordedChunks.length) {
       const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
         type: 'video/webm',
       });
       const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
       const a = document.createElement('a');
       document.body.appendChild(a);
       a.style = 'display: none';
       a.href = url;
       a.download = 'react-webcam-stream-capture.webm';
       a.click();
       window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
       setRecordedChunks([]);
     }
   }, [recordedChunks]);

  const handleStartAgain = () => {
    setIsRecording(false);
    setShowStats(false);
    setIsVideoComplete(false);
    setVideo(null);
    stopTimer();
    setTimer(0);
  };

  const sendVideo = (video) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('video', video, 'interview.webm');

    console.log('Posting Video...', video);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.mainContent}>
        <>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={8} className={classes.rightSection}>
              <Grid container>
                {/* Record Section */}
                <Grid item xs={12} md={12} className={classes.recordingScreen}>
                  <div style={{ height: '480px', width: '100%', position: 'relative' }}>
                    {/* {webcam && ( */}
                    {!video ? (
                      webcamLoading ? (
                        <CircularProgress style={{ height: '2.5rem', width: '2.5rem' }} color="inherit" />
                      ) : (
                        <div className={`webcamContainer ${webcamLoading ? 'webccamLoading' : ''}`}>
                          <Webcam
                            ref={webcamRef}
                            audio={true}
                            mirrored={true}
                            muted={true}
                            onUserMedia={handleUserMedia}
                            style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', objectFit: 'cover' }}
                            videoConstraints={videoConstraints}
                            audioConstraints={audioConstraints}
                          />
                        </div>
                      )
                    ) : (
                      <>
                        {video && (
                          <>
                            <video
                              src={video ? URL.createObjectURL(video) : ''}
                              controls
                              style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', objectFit: 'cover' }}
                              onError={(e) => {
                                console.log('Error', e);
                              }}
                            />
                            {recordedChunks.length > 0 && <button onClick={handleDownload}>Download</button>}
                          </>
                        )}
                      </>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </Grid>

});

export default withStyles(materialStyles)(Index);
```

Comment: I don't use ReactJS but in regular JS you can use `const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);` where you take that updated `url` and use it (for example) as a `myVideo.src= url` for a video tag. In React it might work different (_eg:_ you have to set a `State`? Or maybe also there is a need to use a React equivalent of a blob URL?).

Answer (score 0):

*note: I don't use React so please try to fix any mistake(s) below:*

The solution is to replace the video tag's source with your blob.

A starting point (about the above concept) that you can try...

**(1)**. Use this as your `<video>` tag setup (*eg:* you must set a **ref** for this element):

```
<video
  ref={videoRef}
  type="video/mp4"
  src=""
  controls
  style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', objectFit: 'cover' }}
  onError={(e) => { console.log('Error', e); }}
/>
```

**(2)** Then use that `\\Download Video` function to also play the blob (since you say it has valid data):

```
//# Download Video
const handleDownload = React.useCallback(() => {
 if (recordedChunks.length) 
 {
   const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: 'video/webm' });
   const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   
   //# test playback ...
   videoRef.current.src = url;
   videoRef.current.load();
   videoRef.current.play();
   
   //# save as file
   const a = document.createElement('a');
   document.body.appendChild(a);
   a.style = 'display: none';
   a.href = url;
   a.download = 'react-webcam-stream-capture.webm';
   a.click();
   window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
   setRecordedChunks([]);
 }
}, [recordedChunks] );
```

**PS:** The other thing to be aware of is that on Apple hardware you might be getting video as type `video/mp4` not as type `video/webm`. I'm aware that Safari browser on iOS creates an MP4 video. Just saying that if the HTML tag still doesn't work then consider if your OS and/or browser is affecting the result. 
For example: *Is it not working because you set as `video/webm` in Safari on a Mac / Ipad / Iphone?*